# The RVM-installed mysql2 gem works fine with Rails... but not with a standalone Ruby script

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, mysql2

I have Ruby and Rails installed with RVM in a Mac OS X Lion environment.

I made Rails work properly with the mysql2 gem (using the MAMP libs rather than a mysql install). So everything was fine...

Until I've tried to write a standalone ruby script (out of a Rails context). And now I can't get the mysql2 gem to work.

From within the script or from the Ruby command line (irb), the

```
require "mysql2"
```

instruction leads to the following error:

```
1.9.2p290 :001 > require "mysql2"
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _mysql_get_client_info
  Referenced from: /Users/mick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _mysql_get_client_info
  Referenced from: /Users/mick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

I've tried several stuff:

- `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/mysql/:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`
- using `sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.16.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib`

Nothing worked. I think I'm gonna cry soon...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Strangely, this happened just today with a co-worker. Here's what I did to fix it:

```
gem uninstall mysql2
brew install mysql
gem install mysql2
```

It was as simple as that. Hope it also works for you!

Comment: Often this is caused by 32-bit vs. 64-bit library bindings. The methods are there but for the wrong architecture. Re-installing is the easiest way to resolve these irregularities.

Comment: Thanks, the problem got fixed with your trick. I had to install Homebrew (http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) to do so - i was reluctant to do it as I already had Macports and Fink installed - but it fixed my standalone-Ruby problem without disabling my working Rails app. Homebrew might be my only UNIX package manager in my next clean Mac install!